# What does deep=True do in pyyaml.Loader.construct_mapping?

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

In searching around the web for usages of custom constructors I see things like this:

```
def some_constructor(loader, node):
    value = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
    return SomeClass(value)
```

What does the `deep=True` do? I don't see it in the [pyyaml documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Loader).

It looks like I need it; I have a yaml file generated by a pyyaml representer and it includes node anchors and aliases (like `&id003` and `*id003`); without `deep=True` I get a shallow map back for those objects containing anchors/aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That you don't see `deep=True` in the documentation is because you don't normally need to use it as an end-user of the PyYAML package.

If you trace the use of methods in `constructor.py` that use `deep=` you come to `construct_mapping()` and `construct_sequence()` in class `BaseConstructor()` and both of these call `BaseConstructor.construct_object()`. 
The relevant code in that method to study is:

```
    if tag_suffix is None:
        data = constructor(self, node)
    else:
        data = constructor(self, tag_suffix, node)
    if isinstance(data, types.GeneratorType):
        generator = data
        data = next(generator)
        if self.deep_construct:
            for dummy in generator:
                pass
        else:
            self.state_generators.append(generator)
```

and in particular the `for` loop in there, which only gets executed if `deep=True` was passed in.

Rougly said if the data comes from a constructor is a generator, then it walks over that data (in the `for` loop) until the generator is exhausted. With that mechanism, those constructors can contain a `yield` to create a base object, of which the details can be filled out after the `yield`. Because of their being only one `yield` in such constructors, e.g. for mappings (constructed as Python `dict`s):

```
def construct_yaml_map(self, node):
    data = {}
    yield data
    value = self.construct_mapping(node)
    data.update(value)
```

I call this a two step process (one step to the `yield` the next to the end of the method.

In such two-step constructors the `data` to be yielded is constructed empty, yielded and then filled out. And that has to be so because of what you already noticed: recursion. If there is a self reference to `data` somewhere underneath, `data` cannot be constructed after all its children are constructed, because it would have to wait for itself to be constructed.

The `deep` parameter indirectly controls whether objects that are potentially generators are recursively being built or appended to the list `self.state_generators` to be resolved later on.

Constructing a YAML document then boils down to constructing the top-level objects and looping over the potentially recursive objects in `self.state_generators` until no generators are left (a process that might take more than one pass).

Comment: so if I have recursive data structures, I can't use it (makes sense); why would I have to use it, though? In other words, is there something I can look for in my data that would explain when I need to use `deep=True` ?

Comment: If you dump a data structure that has the same object/mapping/sequence attached at multiple positions you'll get anchors and aliases in your YAML and then you need `deep=True` to be able to load those. If you dump data that at some point has an object that "underneath" itself has a self reference, you will get anchors and aliases as well, but you'll need `deep=True` **and** the two-step process provided by `yield` to be able to load that YAML. So I always make constructors for non-scalars (the potential (self)-recursive ones) with `yield` and `deep=True` although not needed by some YAML docs.

Answer (score 0):

The deep argument controls how nested dictionaries are handled during this process.

When deep=True, the construct_mapping method will recursively call itself on any
nested dictionaries it encounters, and merge the resulting dictionaries together.

for example:

```
a:
  b: 1
  c: 2
d:
  b: 3
```

When "deep=True"

```
{'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}, 'd': {'b': 3}}
```

When "deep=False"

```
{'a': {'c': 2}, 'd': {'b': 3}}
```